# unit step signal

Tags: signal-processing, step-function

I have a question that asks to draw the following signal:

x[n] = u[n] - u[n-2]

I know that
δ[n]=u[n]−u[n−1]
but we are shifting it by 2 so it's different
I don't know how to draw it and how should the graph look like
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UHGj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your graph, looks like it should be 1 for n = 0 and n = 1, and 0 elsewhere

Comment: so my graph is wrong?

Comment: @hamza it depends, what are you trying to graph. you graphed the individual functions u[n] and -u[n-2]. I assume you want to graph the resulting sum of those functions which is what I described.

Comment: how do we sum those functions? like how did we end up saying its 1 for n = 0 and n = 1

Comment: i thought sum means plotting individual functions in the same graph

Comment: @hamza the function x[n] will have a value of 1 when n = 0 and n = 1. everywhere else, it will have a value of 0. you can see that from your graph by adding the values of your functions at each n. for n > 1, you can see that the spikes from u[n] and u[n-2] when added will sum to zero.

Comment: @hamza whether you are supposed to plot the individual functions in the graph or not amounts to 'showing your work' and is a requirement only of the teacher/course layout. the actual function x[n] will look like what i described. hope it makes sense

Comment: it does thanks, another question, I have another question but for the DIRAC signal and its also the sum of functions, this time it will look like I am plotting individual functions right? CZ no values will cancel each others